ASP.NET MVC controller action parameter value with "." doesn't get called
I am having a strange issue with my controller action that it can't be called when my parameter value contains a . (full stop) as show below.
It's working fine when the full stop was removed from the URL parameter. Has anyone else experienced this and is there anything I need to configure in order to get controller recognize the full stop in parameter value? Any suggestion or recommendation will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Failed URL:
https://localhost:40000/mycontroller/Details/ABCD-1.0

Working URL:
https://localhost:40000/mycontroller/Details/ABCD-10


Which version of asp.net are you using, could you also include how you are calling them and the controller details/?

Yeah I'd expect that. Since you can [Route("{parm}.{ext}")], I'd expect the parser to treat . as a break character.

In general,  URLs with certain special characters, such as periods (.), might not be handled correctly due to routing configurations and URL encoding issues. By default, the period character can cause issues because the framework might interpret it as a file extension separator. If you share more details that might be helpful to assist you better.

Try to URL encode your parameter and call your action method like this: https://localhost:40000/mycontroller/Details/ABCD-1%2F0 - does that work?

From Route Templates

URL patterns that attempt to capture a file name with an optional file extension have additional considerations. For example, consider the template files/{filename}.{ext?}. When values for both filename and ext exist, both values are populated. If only a value for filename exists in the URL, the route matches because the trailing . is optional. The following URLs match this route:

/files/myFile.txt
/files/myFile


Which implies that a . will be handled as a break character between route parameters. Though I can't see anywhere that this behaviour is explicitly documented.

Thanks for all yours information and time. Really appreciated it.
After reading through all the replies I did a further searching on the issue.
I did tried on the suggestion to use URL encoding on the value but it's doesn't work for my case. The issue actually is on IIS standard behavior. It will treat value which contain period as a filename with extension. I found this Window.open and pass parameters by post method and change my action using POST instead of GET. Then it's resolved my problem.
Thank you everyone.
